# Spiral example from programming in scala doesn't seem to be working

Tags: scala, spiral

I am learning Scala and was using Programming in Scala book by Martin Odersky. When I was trying example in Chapter 10 it isn't producing the expected result. I tried to modify the code a bit here and there with no luck. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

```
import Element.elem

object Spiral {
  val space = elem(" ")
  val corner = elem("+")

  def spiral(nEdges: Int, direction: Int): Element = {
    if(nEdges == 1)
      corner
    else {
      val sp = spiral(nEdges - 1, (direction + 3) % 4)
      //println("H: " + sp.height + " W: " + sp.width + " D " + direction)
      def verticalBar = elem('|', 1, sp.height - 1) //updated based on google errata which was otherwise def verticalBar = elem('|', 1, sp.height)
      def horizantalBar = elem('-', sp.width, 1)
      if(direction == 0)
        (corner beside horizantalBar) above (sp beside space)
      else if (direction == 1)
        (sp) beside (corner above verticalBar) //updated based on google errata which was otherwise (sp above space) beside (corner above verticalBar)
      else if (direction == 2)
        (space beside sp) above (horizantalBar beside corner)
      else
        (verticalBar above corner) beside (sp) //updated based on google errata which was otherwise (verticalBar above corner) beside (space above sp)
    }
  }

  //Not working as expected, need to debug and fix
  def main (args: Array[String]) {
    val nSides = args(0).toInt
    println(spiral(nSides, 0))
  }
}
```

Here is the expected when run with 14 as argument

```
+-------------
|             
| +---------+ 
| |         | 
| | +-----+ | 
| | |     | | 
| | | +-+ | | 
| | | + | | | 
| | |   | | | 
| | +---+ | | 
| |       | | 
| +-------+ | 
|           | 
+-----------+
```

What I am getting

```
+-------------
| +---------+
```

Comment: What *is* the expected result? What do *you* get?

Comment: Oops forgot to cite what is not working

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be ,

```
def spiral(nEdges: Int, direction: Int): Element = {
if (nEdges == 1)
  elem("+")
else {
  val sp = spiral(nEdges - 1, (direction + 3) % 4)
  def verticalBar = elem('|', 1, sp.height)
  def horizontalBar = elem('-', sp.width, 1)
  if (direction == 0)
    (corner beside horizontalBar) above (sp beside space)
  else if (direction == 1)
    (sp above space) beside (corner above verticalBar)
  else if (direction == 2)
    (space beside sp) above (horizontalBar beside corner)
  else
    (verticalBar above corner) beside (space above sp)
 }
}
```

I haven't run this, could you please check if this works ?

Comment: I first tried this code from book, since it wasn't working post google search where I found errata updated the code. Both aren't working at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didnt update Element class, adding widen and heighten function calls inside above and beside methods.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Were you to have the necessary reputation, you could make this a comment. As it stands, it's a very poor answer. Please consider strengthening it by adding more information, such as a code sample.